# Using Custom Field

Tags: administration, fields, setup

Hi i have created a custom object name Product in that i want to create a custom field by name product_id selected field type as auto increment but the field is not visible help.

Comment: welcome to salesforce.stackoverflow Sathish, please understand that it's hard to answer a question which is so short and without much detail. If you're expected people to make effort to answer, we expect you to make effort asking your question. Where or when is your field not possible ? Providing more details, a clear description , screenshots or code (when applicable) usually improves the quality and understandability of your question.

Answer (score 2):

Auto increment fields will appear only after you create and save a record.  It will not be visible in EDIT page.  Check for the field after saving the record.

If you still can't see it.  Try this. Go to setup--> Objects-->Product.  Open the field you created (product_id__c).  Click on 'View Field Level Security' button.  There check the profile you want this field to be visible.  I assume you are 'System Administrator'.  So tick the box 'Visible' for System Administrator profile.

If you still can't find it.  Go to setup--> Objects-->Product again.  Click on Page Layouts and edit the Products page layout.  Drag and drop the Product Id field into the layout.  Now you can surely see it.

Let me know if you have more issues.